# How to extends FragmentPagerAdapter class?

Tags: fragmentpageradapter

**When I try to extend their class, the FragmentPagerAdapter is deprecated in my Android Studio page code. The problem is very annoying. I have searched a lot but have not found any results.
Please have a look on the page below**

```
package com.example.buyown;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PageAdapter  extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

int tabCount;
public PageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int behavior) {
    super(fm, BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT );
    tabCount= behavior;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position){
        case 0:return new buyOwnTab1();
        case 1:return new buyOwnTab2();
        default: return null;
    }


}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return tabCount;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation at https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter says:

> **This class is deprecated.**
>
> Switch to ViewPager2 and use FragmentStateAdapter instead.

Although technically, based on the internals of FragmentPagerAdapter versus FragmentStateAdapter, FragmentPagerAdapter is simple to follow as it relies on `findFragmentByTag` + `attach` + `detach` + `add`, while FragmentStateAdapter and ViewPager2 relies on a RecyclerView and "periodically executed `gcFragments()` calls" which is significantly trickier, so unless you explicitly require the new behaviors supported by ViewPager2, there is no reason to switch from ViewPager - as standard ViewPager also relies on standard mechanisms supported by Fragments.

That's why `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")` is also a valid solution sometimes, although not always.

IIRC, the major key difference is simpler vertical swipe support, and better RTL support.

Comment: Can you please modify my code, in fact I can't think there proper..?

Comment: Your code is ok, just remove the `tabCount` and return `2` and ignore the deprecation warning in this case

Comment: Then how can I use the (setOnTabSelectedListner) event?

Comment: This does not sound like it is part of the original question?